# Delphi: Getting Copy/Paste to work

Tags: delphi, copy, paste

So I want to add a Copy/Paste function to my Delphi application that draws different shapes and does stuff with them.

Here's the on even handler for the Copy menu item:

```
procedure TForm1.Copy1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Clipboard.Open;
  if SelectShape <> nil then
      clipboard.SetComponent(SelectShape);
   Clipboard.Close;
  end;
```

And I get the error:

```
       Incompatible types: 'TComponent' and 'TBaseShape'
```

TBaseShape is the ancestor class for all shapes in my application

I have no idea why it doesn't work...

Comment: To get it to work, your `TBaseShape` class would have to be `TComponent` class descendant, which is not.

Comment: Also, if `SelectShape` is nil, consider calling `TClipboard.Clear()`, or simply don't open/close the clipboard to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach would be to use a private data format, and serialize your object to XML or another easy-to-debug text-based structure, and put that onto the clipboard.  It would also be useful/polite to render your object (assuming it's a graphic of some sort) onto a Bitmap, and place that on the clipboard as well (clipboard can hold multiple/many formats simultaneously) so that the user can paste into paint, word, etc., and get "something".
Here's a question that does something along these lines, using GPX data

[How to paste a custom format clipboard data into a TMemo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695081/how-to-paste-a-custom-format-clipboard-data-into-a-tmemo)